# Trouble with requests Post function, cannot login

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests

I am currently using Requests library for Python 3.7 to try and login to the [following page](https://portal.projectworx.net/STS/Home/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FSTS%2F%3Fwa%3Dwsignin1.0%26wtrealm%3Dhttps%253a%252f%252fportal.projectworx.net%252fProjectWorx%252f%26wctx%3Drm%253d0%2526id%253dpassive%26wct%3D2020-03-15T14%253a04%253a21Z%26errorMessage%3DYou%2Bare%2Blogged%2Bout.&wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https%3A%2F%2Fportal.projectworx.net%2FProjectWorx%2F&wctx=rm%3D0%26id%3Dpassive&wct=2020-03-15T14%3A04%3A21Z&errorMessage=You%20are%20logged%20out.), following the instructions provided by Julian [here](https://pybit.es/requests-session.html).

Here is what I do:

```
loginSession = requests.Session()    
url = 'https://portal.projectworx.net/STS/Home/GetTenant'
payload = {'UserName': login, 'Password': password}
user_agent = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0'}
login_request = loginSession.post(url, payload, headers=user_agent)

if(login_request.status_code == 200):
    print ("Successful log-in !")
    file = open("login_response.html", "w")
    file.write(login_request.text)
    file.close()

    # Connect to dashboard
    url = 'https://portal.projectworx.net/ProjectWorx/Dashboard/Home'
    dashboard_request = loginSession.get(url)
    file = open("dashboard_request.html", "w")
    file.write(dashboard_request.text) 
    file.close()
```

Although I have theoretically achieved establishing a connection (Return code 200), both "login_request.html" and "dashboard_request.html" end-up containing the initial login page.

**Note:** A deviation I have found between Julian's example and mine, is that I cannot find the input names for "user" and "password" when inspecting the login page's HTML code. Instead, I found the following:

```
<input id="TenantId" name="TenantId" type="hidden" value="">
```

Not sure how to pass the right input-parameters to "Post" with this type of form.

**Edit 1:**

After using Pete's method for sniffing the requests in the Network tab and using the right input data (UserName and Password), I have gotten the following content in the login_response.html (created from "login_request.text")

[image: Screenshot of login_request.html]

Which seems way better than before, given that it seems to reflect what the browser is receiving. But attempting a get on the Dashboard nevertheless still returns the login page. The "loginSession.cookies" is still empty after the login request, not sure how normal this is.

**Edit 2:**

On browser side, from looking at the traffic after logging-in in the Network tab, I observe the following:

[image: Network traffic]

The first couple of login-related lines contain the following cookie in the Request header:

```
_ga=****; _gac_****
```

And then (for the line highlighted for instance), it embeds the following cookie:
FedAuth=******; _ga=****; *gac*****; .ASPXAUTH=********

But because I can't seem to catch the cookies, I don't know what to do with this information..

Further help would again be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Do you need those url parameters there... maybe try with: `url = 'https://portal.projectworx.net/STS/Home/Login` instead... it may be you login okay,but the return url you're requesting attempts to take you do a page you don't have permission to view, hence you get a login request again...

Comment: Hi Jon, I thought so too but it seems not. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Anyone? Please? : C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a web developer tool to reverse engineer the login process for this particular site. You probably don't need to bother routing around in the HTML, rather replicate the POST request being made by the browser. In Chrome and Firefox you can press F12 and select the Network tab, then log in normally and observe what gets sent to the server.

Unfortunately without an account I can't tell you exactly what needs to be sent, but at a glance.

The URL you need to POST to is in fact https://portal.projectworx.net/STS/Home/GetTenant rather than https://portal.projectworx.net/STS/Home/Login

The form data (payload) you are submitting should also be {'UserName': login, 'Password': password} rather than what you're using.

Attached picture shows what I'm looking at in the Chrome Developer Tools, Network tab. This POST was triggered after pressing the Login button, with a username of test and a password of test input into the respective input fields.

[image]

Comment: Hi Pete,
Thank you very much for the pointers! This helped a lot understand better what Requests is trying to do.. 
Now although the login part seems clear, it looks like I have a subsequent question related to keeping the connection alive (misuse of sessions maybe?). Do you think you could have a look, please (updated OP)?

Comment: Hey. Your use of sessions looks okay if your example code is still the same? Ensure you don't create a new Session object. Do the Developer Tools show any cookies being set when you log in yourself via the browser?

Comment: Hi again Pete, thanks for following up. I have updated the post based on your hint, it'd be great if you could have another look. Thanks very much for supporting. ; )

Comment: After the POST to GetTenant, there is a POST to Login, I wonder what is sent and received by that POST and whether any cookies are set etc? In fact, all the network comms before the GET on Home are worth investigating.
The _ga=****; _gac_**** cookies are Google Analytics related. FedAuth and ASPXAUTH are worth looking at.

Comment: Ah yes, seems I missed this one, here is roughly what it contains:
" .ASPXAUTH=9FF961EB7DC***etc.; path=/; HttpOnly "
But I don't see what I could do with this..